# Implement 'refreshing gridview data on a form when another form closes' for all forms

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

Right now. I am doing this

```
private CustomerProfileMain mainForm;
public CustomerProfileForm(CustomerProfileMain form)
{
  InitializeComponent();
   mainForm = form;
}
```

CustomerProfileForm_closing:

```
mainForm.RefreshGrid();
```

CustomerProfileMain Code:

```
gridControl2.DataSource = new Entity().Customers.toList();
```

This updates this form. But as I have 30+ forms and MainForms requiring to do this. How do I implement a method in a `Home()` class to do this on every Form close for its user control?

`Home()` is parentform of all Main forms`(XtraUserControl)`. and `CustomerProfileForm` is of type `DevExpress.XtraForm`.

Comment: You can use an Interface. If all Forms that are injected with a `CustomerProfileMain` (or similar) class implement the same Interface, the class that creates them can subscribe to the `FormClosing` event and, when one of these Forms closes, the *Parent* class can cast `sender` to the Interface they share and call a public method (defined by the Interface) that performs this task.

Comment: do I understand correctly that, I create 2 methods `FormClosing` and `Refresh` inside the `IRefreshable` interface in Home class. Then all `Main` userControl implement `Refresh` and all subforms implement `FormClosing` method

Comment: It depends on how this procedure works and what you actually want to achieve. It looks like you don't want to add a `FormClosing` handler to all `CustomerProfileForm` which then calls the public `Refresh()` method of another class. That's understandable. You have different methods: 1) Implement an Interface in `CustomerProfileForm` that exposes the `CustomerProfileMain` you inject as a `protected internal` property (you have a instance field now). The *Parent* class can subscribe to the `FormClosing` when it creates a `CustomerProfileForm` object...

Comment: ... When the event is raised, it can use the property exposed through the Interface to access the injected object and call its public method. 2) If there's a single class that is responsible for creating both these other two classes (`CustomerProfileMain` and `CustomerProfileForm`), then it holds (or can hold) a reference to both. As before, when the `FormClosing` event is raised, it uses the `sender` object to determine which Form is closing and then calls the public method of its injected object. The instances can be stored in a `Dictionary<class, class>`. Many other methods.

Comment: I, personally, prefer to implement an Interface when specific classes types need to *collaborate* to to perform a common task, to enforce the *contract*. But you have many other methods. I assume you don't use MVC/MVP and maybe you don't want to go down that road now. There's also a chance to implement a Factory pattern... and so on.